# Merge to master ignoring a bad commit on master

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a real mess on my hands but I am sure there will be a trick to fix it.

We used to have a developer who would keep a separate branch for every software 'version' which was awful as a bug fix would have to be cherry picked onto every branch. For the repo in question there were 6 concurrent branches.

In reality, various bug fixes occurred on each branch. So every branch had something quite different on it. That developer had now left and I would like to merge all the branches back onto master. I did the following (two feature branches illustrated for clarity):

```
M0 - M1 - M2 - - - - - - - - - - M3* - M4 - M5 - M6
 \    \                                     /   /
  \    fB - fB - fB - fB - - - - - - - - - -   /
   fA - fA - fA - fA - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

This looked OK, but there is one major problem. In commit 'M3*' **every** file in the repository was committed as the file permissions had changed. No functional changes occurred to the files. 
This commit happened more recently than the commits in the feature branches, so when I merge, this is the version that gets chosen.

All of the above badness has been pushed to the remote.

I would like to merge all the changes (including the changes in M2 and M4) but ignore the changes in M3*.

How could I go about this?

Comment: The "recent-ness" of commits is entirely irrelevant to `git merge`. What matters is the *diff* from the merge base commit—for `M5` that's `M1`—to the two branch-tips; for `M5` that's the diff from `M1` to `M4`, and from `M1` to the last `fB` commit, whatever that may be. The graph (which you've drawn here) is the key to merging. Find the merge base, find the two branch-tip commits, and compare the merge base to each branch-tip. Combining these snapshots, plus any high-level operations like `chmod`s or renames, is how merge works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do it without rewriting neither local nor remote history would be to [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) commit `M3`

It would not delete or change `M3` in any way, just create a new commit (let's call it `M7`) containing the exact opposite changes brought by `M3` :

```
git revert M3
```

```
M0 - M1 - M2 - - - - - - - - - - M3* - M4 - M5 - M6 - M7
 \    \                                     /   /
  \    fB - fB - fB - fB - - - - - - - - - -   /
   fA - fA - fA - fA - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: Note that you might want to revert `M3` as a commit that goes where `M5` shows here, and only *then* do the two merge commands (producing `M6` and `M7` as the two merges). If you have already made M5-and-M6 and don't want to re-make them for any particular reason, though, just fixing things up afterwards is fine.

Comment: @torek Absolutely, I took as a constraint that history was unrewritable here, but you're right.